# Flowtype - how to write declaration for class factories, such as Backbone Models?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, flowtype

Extensive googling and reading through Flow docs and examples didn't show any example of a very common pattern in Javascript - having functions that return classes. A canonical example is Backbone:

```
var User = Backbone.Model.extend({
  getFullName: function() {
    return this.get('firstName') + ' ' + this.get('lastName');
  }
});  


var exampleUser = new User();
exampleUser.set('firstName', 'Johny'); //set() is a method from Backbone.Model
exampleUser.set('lastName', 'Something');
exampleUser.getFullName(); //method coming from User class
```

In JSDoc, I could annotate the class as follows, with some IDEs being able to figure out a decent autocompletion:

```
/**
 * @class User
 * @augments Backbone.Model
 */
var User = Backbone.Model.extend(/**@lends User.prototype */{
  getFullName: function() {...}
});
```

Is there any way how to properly annotate this pattern in Flow?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
/* @flow */

class Model {
    get(name: string): any {}
    set(name: string, value: any): void {}
}

function extend<T>(def: T): Class<Model & T> {
    throw new Error('not implemented')
}

var User = extend({
    getFullName: function() {
        return this.get('firstname') + this.get('lastname')
    }
})

var a = new User

a.get('firstname')
a.getFullName()
// a.notExisting give error
```

I use [intersection type](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/intersections/) and [generic type](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/generics/) to express the pattern that '**Given a definition object type `T`, return a `Class` that is both `Model` and `T`**'

This code compiles under brew-shipped flow 0.11

---

Below is my personal idea on flow. I have to agree that flow docs is scarce. The best way to learn its feature is probably reading flow's [React annotation and flow's source.](http://sitr.us/2015/05/31/advanced-features-in-flow.html) Flow is based on a sophisticated type inference algorithm, which allows you type-check a program without annotation. So Flow is designed to make you not annotate, and so does its documentation. However, type inference is not so advanced to free one from annotating. You code is an example.

Comment: Just a small nit: Flow does not use H-M type inference. It uses flow analysis (hence, Flow). Thanks for providing this answer!