# How to flowtype mix-in class factories?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I'm migrating to Flow an internal JavaScript framework that heavily relies on ES6 [mix-in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Mix-ins), with class factories structured along the lines of:

```
function Mixin(Base) {
  return class extend Base {

    constructor() { super() }

    mixin() { … }

  }
}
```

but I'm unable to write correct generic type annotations for such methods.

So far my best guess is:

```
interface IMixin {

  mixin():void;

}

function Mixin<T>(Base: Class<T>): Class<T & IMixin> {
  return class extend Base implements IMixin {

    constructor() { super() }

    mixin() { … }

  }
}
```

which is loosely related to https://stackoverflow.com/a/33030114/739773, but invariable causes Flow to complain with `Flow: Cannot return 'class { ... }' because class '<<anonymous class>>' [1] is incompatible with 'T' [2].`, regardless of the minor variations I tested.

What am I missing? Any hints short of disabling type checking for such functions?

Comment: apparently not feasible :-( see https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/7595#issuecomment-478151944